# clearTimeout does not work in ondblclick event in FireFox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm trying to have an element which support both click and double click on it. But the following example works in IE but does not work in FireFox 3.5.6:

```
<button onclick="c=setTimeout('alert(1);',1000);" ondblclick="clearTimeout(c);alert(2);">Test</button>
```

It just doesn't clear timeout, so alert(1) is being fired.
Does anyone know what is the issue? 
How I can have click and double click events separately in FireFox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you double-click in Firefox, you get two click events and then a dblclick event. So you're setting two timers and clearing one. Clearing the timer on the click event should work:

```
<button onclick="clearTimeout(c);c=setTimeout('alert(1);',1000);" ondblclick="clearTimeout(c);alert(2);">Test</button>
```

Comment: This only works in IE due to a bug with the way IE fires events on the way to a double click. See here for details: http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2008/01/bug-263-beware-of-doubleclick-in-ie.html In short the second mousedown and second click never fire.

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't be inlining your javascript in your HTML.  I would suggest using a JavaScript library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) for this.  jQuery will solve the cross browser event issues that you are having!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var c;
    $("button").click(function() {
        c = setTimeout(function() {
            alert(1);
        }, 1000);
    }).dblclick(function() {
        clearTimeout(c);
        alert(2);
    });
});
```

Comment: It is like in your code. I just simplified it significantly for this example.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get it. It still doesn't work. I mean, if you put a clerTimeout in the onclick event the onclick event wont work since you stop it before you have finished it :S
Actually I don't see how you could say "This fixed the issue" ?? Just try and copy that very code you wrote and you'll realise that nothing happends... :/

Comment: The code sample provided by Annie might not work, but the idea is absolutely correct and it did solve my issue.